Optimal way for a client to request ~100 tiny files in parallel
Due to the specific nature of our product requirements, end users on our mobile app occasionally need to request 40 to 120 tiny files stored in Supabase Storage (S3 wrapper).
Each file is ~10KB, so total response payload size is 400KB to 1.2MB. The request needs to be as fast as possible, and unfortunately cannot be lazy loaded, queued, etc. It also can't be cached often due to the many permutations inherit in file permissions across users.
Originally, the requests were done in parallel on device, but were throttled by the OS, so it took ~10 seconds.
Since these requests are sporadic but not continuous, it's not economical for us to run a server all the time to just handle these requests while the rest of our platform is serverless. Also, a single server, not on the edge, wouldn't be able to take advantage of the files themselves on the edge via CDN.
Next, I moved the requests into a Supabase edge function. But due to cold start time and other issues with Supabase optimization, the average request was ~3.5 seconds (even when warm).
The most optimized solution I have right now is a Cloudflare worker that persists user via auth header to leverage Supabase Storage policies:
  const token = authHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');
  const { data } = await supabase.auth.getUser(token);

Then runs all file requests in parallel, then returns to the client.
Also, Supabase has request throttling to storage, so only 20 files max can be requests per Cloudflare worker instance before the response times from Supabase degrade beyond acceptability.
Therefore, I'm batching requests client side and running Cloudflare workers in parallel to avoid Supabase throttling, with the knock on effect of avoiding Cloudflare subrequest limits:
const batchSize = Platform.OS === 'web' ? 5 : 10;

const fileBatches = [];

for (let i = 0; i < metadata.length; i += batchSize) {
    const batch = metadata.slice(i, i + batchSize);
    batches.push(batch);
}

const requests = batches.map(async (batch) => {
    const fileIds = batch.map((file) => file.id);

    const response = await fetch('https://cloudflare.worker.instance', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            ...(authHeaderToken && {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authHeaderToken}`,
            }),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            parentId,
            batchFileIds: fileIds,
        }),
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    return result.files;
});

const responses = await Promise.all(requests);

The batch size is adjusted based on client device, based on average, reasonable parallel request limits (not resorting to the original device throttling issue):

Mobile: 4-6 requests
Web: 6-8 requests

Now, the average response time from the parallel Cloudflare requests total is ~500-700ms.
This response time is acceptable for now, but is not ideal. Our target is 300ms.
Am I missing some obvious way to handle this issue, or is there a more optimized method?
